# Asymptotic of the sum of squared primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, asymptotics

I have a rather simple question of number theory which I can't seem to be able to find a good reference for. I am not a specialist and I don't really know where to look. I would like to show that the following sequence

$$  \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{p \leq N \ p  \ \mathrm{prime }}{p^2} $$ goes to infinity. Numerical computation indicates that it is true.

Thank you very much for your attention :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49383/how-does-sum-px-p-s-grow-asymptotically-for-textres-1/49434#49434 (and the vote to close as duplicate option does not work for posts existing on MSE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question appeared on Math.stackexhange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49383/how-does-sum-px-p-s-grow-asymptotically-for-textres-1/49434#49434). The answer linked above uses partial summation to show that for $k>-1$ we have
$$\sum_{p\leq x}p^{k}=\text{li}\left(x^{k+1}\right)+O\left(x^{k+1}e^{-c\sqrt{\log x}}\right).$$

Answer (score 3):

By the prime number theorem, the number of primes between $N/2$ and $N$ is on the order of $N/\log N.$ So, the sum of just those primes squared is of order $N^3/ \log N.$

Comment: "Is on the order of $\log N$" I believe you mean $N/\log N$, and the resulting sum of squares has order $N^3/\log N$.

Comment: @EricNaslund That's what happens when you don't sleep :(